# Bash - how to exclude directory with find command and how to get full path with find?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

so I have the code right now down below, and I'm running into a few problems with it

1. I'm having trouble excluding the directories being outputted by

   ```
   find ${1-.}
   ```

   It is giving me the directories too instead of only names; I've tried different methods such as -prune etc.
2. I'm having trouble with deleting the empty files

The data given to me by

```
    EMPTY_FILE=$(find ${1-.} -size 0)
```

Does not give me the correct path
Here is the output for that

```
    TestFolder/TestFile
```

in this case I can't just do:

```
    rm TestFolder/TestFile
```

As it is invalid path; since it needs ./TestFolder/TestFile

How would I add on the ./ or is there away to get the full path.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "Here are all the files in the directory specified\n"
    find ${1-.}

    EMPTY_FILE=$(find ${1-.} -size 0)
    echo "Here are the list of empty files\n"
    echo "$EMPTY_FILE \n"
    echo "Do you want to delete those empty files?(yes/no)"
    read text
    if [ "$text" == "yes" ]; then $(rm -- $EMPTY_FILE); fi
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `As it is invalid path; since it needs ./TestFolder/TestFile` that's wrong.

Comment: is there a way to get a full file path using find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "Here are all the files in the directory specified\n"

# Use -printf "%f\n" to print the filename without leading directories
# Use -type f to restrict find to files
find "${1-.}" -type f -printf "    %f\n"

echo -e "Here are the list of empty files\n"

# Again, use -printf "%f\n"
find "${1-.}" -type f -size 0 -printf "    %f\n"

echo -e "Do you want to delete those empty files?(yes/no)"
read answer

# Delete files using the `-delete` option
[ "$answer" = "yes" ] && find "${1-.}" -type f -size 0 -delete
```

Also note that I've quotes `"${1-.}"` at all occurrences. Since it is user input, you can't rely on the input. Even if it is a path, it might still contain problematic characters, like spaces.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that find actually has a `-delete` flag. Also has an `-exec` flag if you need to run other commands with those files.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm having trouble excluding the directories being outputted by
>
> ```
> find ${1-.}
> ```
>
> It is giving me the directories too instead of only names

You are looking for the `-type` test.  To instruct `find` to report only regular files, you could say

```
find ${1-.} -type f
```

That's probably what you really want, but what you actually asked (to exclude only directories) would be

```
find ${1-.} -not -type d
```

Excluding only directories will list symbolic links and special files, too.

> in this case I can't just do:
>
> ```
> rm TestFolder/TestFile
> ```
>
> As it is invalid path; since it needs ./TestFolder/TestFile

Nonsense.  `./TestFolder/TestFile` means exactly the same thing as `TestFolder/TestFile`.

In any event, `find` *does* print paths starting at the specified starting path(s).

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that I'm missing something from your question, but if all you need to do is exclude directories, just tell find to only look for files:

```
find . -type f -size 0 -delete
```

And then adjust that to suit your script. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
-size 0 -type f
```

rm with no option will not delete directories . Your claim that rm needs ./ is wrong anyway.